# Problem using css sprites as the background for title

Tags: background, css-sprites, css

I have a master css sprite for my website. Now I have problems with backgrounds for few article titles. I created image with rounded corners. Now I apply this background for my title, I dont see the complete background image, part of the image gets cropped. I want to apply 100% of the image as background.

```
background: #E8E8E8 url(/img/icons/spritelnkd.png) no-repeat 0px -180px;
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either you use the css3 border-radius option and drop the background image, or you need to bloat your markup a bit and introduce a second container with a background image for one side of your title. This technique is described for tabs in this article:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Answer (score 0):

Map the width of your image with it's place holder.

eg:
if your image width 100px, use as follows

```
<div style="width:100px;" class="sprite-class">Title</div>
```